# 'Missing command error' in cordova-screenshot plugin

Tags: cordova, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot in my cordova application. I am using https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot plugin.

```
  navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
      if(error){
        console.error(error);
      }else{
        console.log('ok',res.filePath);
      }
    },'jpg',50);
```

console.error('error') throws 'Missing Command Error'.. Any help?

Comment: Some files is missing in plugin, like .java or .js file. Please check.

Comment: This get fail only in browser. Works in my build. :) Thanks!!

Comment: @Meroshini any progress on this ? I am chasing a similar one where the file plugin is the root cause (in Chrome only). Does you app break in all browsers or just Chrome ?

Comment: This is a device plugin. Like camera, it won't work in browsers.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the plugin.xml file, you can see that this plugin only supports Android, IOS, and OSX